# Batch fetch Parse and Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fetch

Using Swift 2 and Parse 1.9.1, I cannot seem to find the `fetchAll()` function. Working with a single `PFObject`, the following seems to work where `object` is a `PFObject`:

```
object.fetchInBackground()
```

However when trying to fetch an array of `PFObjects` with `fetchAllInBackground()`, which the documentation seems to allow, the code completion tool does not find any such method. Has the function changed names and if so, how can I use it? As a note, the way that I am trying to use the method is as follows, where `listOfObjects` is an array of `PFObjects`:

```
listOfObjects.fetchAllInBackground()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchAllInBackground:) you will see that `fetchAllInBackground` and the related methods are class methods on `PFObject`, they are not functions of the array class.

You would call it as `PFObject.fetchAllInBackground(listOfObjects)`

Comment: I did read the documentation but the Obj-C was quite confusing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you see a + in front of a method declaration in Objective C it means that it is a class method

Answer (score 0):

fetchAlInBackground: is a class method.

```
PFObject.fetchAllInBackground(listOfObjects)
```